# Как в запросе выбрать строки с двумя знаками препинания подряд?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Как в SQL запросе выбрать те строки, в которых два знака (или символа) препинания идут подряд?

Например:

```
id      number
----- --------
1          1-2
2           +*
3          1\!
```

Ожидаемый результат: выбрать `id 2,3`.

---

PS Oracle без программных расширений.

Comment: А если через like ? С регуляркой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю вам помогут [регулярные выражения](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Спасибо, помогли.

Answer (score 3):

Знаки препинания - это POSIX класс символов `[:punct:]`. Он поддерживается [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19):

```sql
select str, 
    case when regexp_like (str, '[[:punct:]]{2}') then 'y' else 'n' end match
from (
    select trim(column_value) str 
    from xmlTable ('"abc+*123","def,/456","zz\!zz"') test_strings);

STR              MATCH
---------------- -----
abc+*123         y    
def,/456         y    
zz\!zz           y
```